# Any ideas how to solve this log inequality?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

$\log_{\frac 12 }x > \log_{\frac 13 }x $

I don't know how to move with it :/

Comment: 1st: write your question using Mathjax; 2nd: you have to rewrite the logs in the same base.

Comment: It is strange that you are unable to apply the definition : $ln(x)/(ln(1/2))>ln(x)/(ln(1/3))$, then take care because the denominators are negative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to prove:

$$\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) > \log_{\frac{1}{3}}(x)$$

By the change-of-base formula:

$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\frac{1}{2})} > \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\frac{1}{3})}$$

$$-\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)} > -\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(3)}$$

Multiplying both sides by $-\ln(2)\ln(3)$ (and flipping the inequality sign):

$$\ln(3)\ln(x) > \ln(2)\ln(x)$$

For $x\neq 1$:

$$\ln(3)>\ln(2)$$

Which is true. Thus, the original inequality is true for $x\neq 1$. If $x = 1$, then $\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \log_{\frac{1}{3}}(x) = 0$. Thus:

$$\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) > \log_{\frac{1}{3}}(x)\text{ for }x\in(0, 1)\cup(1,\infty)$$

($x$ must also be positive for its logarithms to exist.)

Comment: You are to nice to give a complete answer to somebody who is unable to begin such an exercise...

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm sorry, I'm not as smart as you

Comment: @OdiZ It's not at all a question of smartness. You have to **work first**, and this begins by reading your lecture notes. You would have at once find the definition of $\log_a$. Too many people ask a question without showing their attempts...